# How to display overflow text in datagrid cell

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid, tooltip

I have a a column in a datagrid in WPF that has text that will overflow. I am trying to find a way to display the text to the user when they hover the mouse over the cell/column. I am thinking that utilizing the tooltip will be the easiest/best way to go but I can't figure out how.

**EDIT:**

I am currently trying to accomplish this by creating a style in the XAML WPF code:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" x:Key="toolTipCell">
        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Cell content here"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

And then doing this code in the code in the AutoGeneratingColumn event:

```
    If e.PropertyName = "MasterName" Then
        'e.Cancel = True
        e.Column.Width = New DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star)
        e.Column.CellStyle = TryCast(FindResource("toolTipCell"), Style)
    End If
```

But I don't know how to make the cell's value be the value of the tool tip

Comment: `Tooltip` is a way to go. Have you tried out something which is not working?

Comment: @RohitVats I am not sure how to implement the tooltip for this purpose.

Comment: @RohitVats I have updated the OP with some code I am trying. Do you have any thoughts on how to make the cell contents be the value of the tooltip?